# Sublime Text 3 - Triggering one plugins functionality when another plugin is used

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublimg Text 3 with both the [git plugin](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git) and the [Rsync SSH plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Rsync%20SSH).  Whenever I change branches in Sublime, I would like it to trigger the "Rsync entire project to remotes" command that's provided by Rsync SSH.  With this set up, as soon as I trigger a branch switch in Sublime, my remotes will be updated with the latest branch as well.  Is there any way to do this with just Sublime and standard configurations, or will I need to write a plugin to integrate these two processes?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you edited the rsync plugin, you don't really have too many options. You could create a build script that does *both* of these tasks for you or even move out of Sublime and hook your git up to do a `post-checkout` call. Rsync is really simple it should be pretty easy. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks